# React-Native import a library and make available in multiple components

Tags: javascript, import, module, react-native, ecmascript-6

How should I import a library/module into React-Native and make it available in multiple components?

Is there a standard way of doing this without having to import, and configure, the library in every component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually handle these situations by creating my own wrapper module that configures and exports the library. Then when I use it in my app, I use the local wrapper module. For example:

myLibrary.js

```
import library from 'library';

library.configure({ /* options */ });

export default library;
```

someOtherModule.js

```
import library from './myLibrary';

library.doThings();
```